# how to install certificate by command?

Tags: import, installation, certificate

I would like to install a certificate on a live and acceptance windows server. It should be possible with some command. I have did it before but cannot find it. I think it was something with "WinHttpCertCfg.exe".

Does someone know what the command is, or can send me to some website. Thanks alot..

Comment: Hi, have you solve this? How?

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it in **Windows 7** and **Windows 10**. Here is the command:

```
certutil -f -addstore CA <file_with_extension_and_complete_path>

#certutil -f -addstore CA "D:\test\random.der"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Windows Certificate Store using commandline:

`certmgr.exe -add "Path\To\Cert\MyCertificate.cer" -s -trustedpublisher`

You will need, of cause, administrative rights do this.

You can find further information [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc732061%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

**Hint**: If you are adding a self-signed certificate you will need to add the certificate which the *new one* derives, too. (*Example*: If you created your own CA intermediate certificate, you will need to add this to the Certificate Store as well)

Answer (score 0):

I make it works with the following command:

`certmgr.exe /c /add my_cert.cer /s root`

FYI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/e78byta0(VS.80).aspx